# Restriction of a sheaf to a fibre

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I have come across the notion of the restriction of a sheaf to a fibre, but I haven't been able to find a proper definition, could anyone perhaps supply one?

Suppose that $f: X \to Y$ is a morphism of schemes. Let $y \in Y$. Then $X_y = X \times_Y Spec \ k(y)$ is the fibre of $y$. Suppose further that $\mathcal{L}$ is a sheaf on $X$. What is meant by $\mathcal{L}_y$, the restriction of $\mathcal{L}$ to the fibre?

Comment: I would expect it to be the pullback of $\mathcal L$ to $X_y$ via the canonical map $X_y\to X$.

Comment: @Brad Thanks, this makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

I believe it usually means the pullback of $\mathcal{L}$ to $X_y$ when you're in the context of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules, as the comment above says. Be careful, though, since Hartshorne initially defines the restriction of a sheaf to a closed subset as the inverse image sheaf, not the pullback. However, when you have an $\mathcal{O}_X$ -module, for most uses you want the restriction to be an $\mathcal{O}_{X_y}$-module as well.

In this case, one way to see the pullback to the fiber is as $\mathcal{L}\otimes k(y)$, where $k(y)$ is the residue field of $y$; this gives a sheaf on $X$ that is the pushforward of the restriction of $\mathcal{L}$ to $X_y$ and is usually identified with the restricted sheaf.

Comment: How do we see $\mathcal{L}\otimes k(y)$ as a sheaf on $X_y$, $k(y)$ is a sheaf on $Y$ supported at $\{\bar{y}\}$ right?

Comment: Yes, but $X_y:=X\times_Y k(y)$, and $k(y)$ is an $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathcal{L}\otimes f^*k(y) $? Because $k(y) $ is an $\mathcal{O}_Y$ module and we need a sheaf on $X$.

Comment: You only need to see $k(y)$ as a sheaf on $X_y:=X\times_Y\mbox{Spec}(k(y))$. Since $k(y)$ is an $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module, it makes sense to look at it as a sheaf on the product.

Comment: This may be a stupid question. But how do we look at $k(y) $ as a sheaf on $X_y$? Via the pull back?